# DBI::dbAppendTable throws unused argument params error

Tags: r, rmysql, r-dbi

I've been trying to use dbAppendTable but have not been able to get it to work.

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test", password = password)

dbCreateTable(con, "iris", iris)

df <- data.frame(Species = "rose")
dbAppendTable(con, "iris", df)

dbDisconnect(con)
```

This gives the error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  unused argument (params = list("rose"))
```

I get the same error if I use dbExecute with params like dbAppendTable:

```
DBI::dbExecute(con, "INSERT INTO iris (Species) VALUES (?)", params = list("rose"))
```

but not when I use dbExecute without params

```
 dbExecute(con, "INSERT INTO iris (Species) VALUES ('rose')")
```

Comment: I think `RMySQL` has not implemented `params=`. Try using `RMariaDB` instead, I believe it is 100% compatible, and appears to be better-maintained than `RMySQL`.